# How to electrically hook up my humidifier to my furnace and have it run when furnace is running and not A/C in summer

Tags: hvac, furnace, humidifier

How do I hook up my humidifier to my furnace so it only runs when furnace heats my house.  Just want to make sure it does not turn on when A/C in summer goes on.  The person who installed my furnace did not hook it up and is not answering my calls.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On most newer furnaces, on the control board there are specific terminals for a humidifier.  The engineers have built into this control board the exact criteria that you are looking for.